# Design a class named Time in java

Tags: java, class, time

I have been working on this code for 2 days and all I have is this. I think I made some progress and I think I'm almost done. The only problem I have is in my public Time(long elapseTime) constructor. The read out is not formatted correctly or I did something wrong. Time t2 = new Time(1382832000) should display 384,120 hours but it only displays 384 hours. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class Time{
    private long hour;
    private long minute;
    private long second;

  public Time(){
    //this(System.currentTimeMillis());
    second = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis()/ 1000) % 60 ;
    minute = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 / 60) % 60;
    hour   = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 / 60 / 60) % 24;

  }

  public Time(long elapseTime){
    //setTime(elapseTime);
    second = (elapseTime / 1000);
    minute = (elapseTime / 1000 / 60);
    hour   = (elapseTime / 1000 / 60 / 60);
  }
  Time(int hour, int minute, int second){
      /*hour = ((this.hour >= 0 && this.hour < 24) ? this.hour : 0);
      minute = ((this.minute >= 0 && this.minute < 6) ? this.minute : 0);
      second = ((this.second >= 0 && this.second < 24) ? this.second : 0);*/
      this.hour = hour;
      this.minute = minute;
      this.second = second;
    }
    public void setTime(long elapseTime){
      second = (int) (elapseTime / 1000) % 60 ;
      minute = (int) ((elapseTime / (1000*60)) % 60);
      hour   = (int) ((elapseTime / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
    }
     public long getHour() {
        return hour;
    }

    public long getMinute() {
        return minute;
    }

    public long getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

   public String toString(){
       return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", getHour(), getMinute(), getSecond());
   }

}
```

to test it...

```
public class TestTimeClass{
   public static void main(String [] args){

      Time t1 = new Time();
      System.out.println(t1);
      //System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
      Time t2 = new Time(1382832000);
      System.out.println(t2);
      t2.setTime(555550000);
      System.out.println(t2);

   }

}
```

the output is ...
22:50:47
384:23047:1382832 // this should be more like 384,120 : 23,047,200 : 1,382,832,000
10:19:10

Comment: It seems to be doing what it is instructed to do.  1382832000 divided by a thousand is 1382832.  Do you intend timeElapsed to be in seconds or milliseconds?

Comment: the time is in milliseconds

Comment: The output you expected would be ok if timeElapsed was given in seconds.  Try and append units to your identifiers.

Comment: It looks like a rounding error. Integer division truncates. add a '.0' to each 1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class is very confusing. You seem to want to represent both 24 hour time of day as well as elapsed time.

Also, you should check your math since 1382832000 milliseconds is 384 hours.

Comment: I would like it to show in 12 hour format but I have been unsuccessful in making that happen.  
A no-arg constructor that creates a Time object for the current time. (The values of the data fields will represent the current time.)      A constructor that constructs a Time object with a specified elapsed time since midnight, January 1, 1970, in milliseconds. (The values of the data fields will represent this time.)
A constructor that constructs a Time object with the specified hour, minute, and second.

Comment: I see. It seems my Time() constructor's math is off and my time is wrong I think. its 7:34 here in GA but the time is displaying 11:34